# Is it possible to create a parent variable in a child class? AS3

Tags: variables, actionscript-3

Let's say I am I want to create a variable for the parent inside a class.

```
var parent.myvar:Number = 0;
```

Does not work, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot **declare** variables in parent. But if the parent is a dynamic instance (like generic **MovieClip**) you can just create a new field with **parent.myvar = 0;** statement.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Why is it necessary for the Child to create the variable inside a Parent class? The more you explain your goal the easier it is to give alternative solutions...